# Cassandra query fails when I add more parameters to WHERE clause

Tags: python, database, cassandra

I've tried to run the following query on a database I'm working on:

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM x.y WHERE box=" + boxID + " and tag='notification';"
```

This query seemed to work, but after some iterations with different boxIDs, it started to fail, raising the following exception:  
 `cassandra.ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_respons es': 0, 'failures': 1`}. 
Not knowing how to proceed, I tried to remove the tag clause, resulting in the following query:

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM chronicles.box_botany WHERE box=" + boxID + ";"
```

which, to my surprise, doesn't raise the exception anymore.
Shouldn't making the WHERE clause more specific speed up the process?
How much slower is checking for that specific condition in python compared to checking it with cassandra? Why did the starting query work with some IDs, but failed with others?

In case it helps, I'm working on cassandra through python. These are the step I follow to setup the connection with the database:

```
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=CASSANDRA_USER, password=CASSANDRA_PASS)
cluster = Cluster(contact_points=[CASSANDRA_HOST], port=CASSANDRA_PORT,auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect(CASSANDRA_DB)
session.row_factory = dict_factory
```

Then to retrieve the results and work on them I do the following:

```
for row in session.execute(sql_query):
  #stuff
```

Comment: Can you include the table schema for x.y, tell us how many nodes are in the Cassandra cluster and the replication factor for x.

Comment: Could you post the complete schema of the `x.y` table? Does your primary key look like `PRIMARY KEY ((boxID), tag)`? When you execute the same query within the CQLSH, does it work?